# Why is Search filter working a level too high?

Tags: core-data, uisearchbar, swiftui

My coreData driven list is working correctly, but the searchBar isn't working at the right level, it is searching a level higher?
So... Instead of filtering the names within the list, it appears to be focussed on the name of the data model itself...NOT the contents within the model as I expected.

I figured I probably needed to add an additional ForEach statement just below the first, but I can't get that to work.

The WIP project is here https://github.com/my4paws/DogBiz-swiftui

```
List {
    ForEach(self.dogListVM.dogs.filter {
        self.searchTerm.isEmpty ?
        true :
        "\($0)".localizedCaseInsensitiveContains(self.searchTerm)
     }, id: \.dogName) { dog in

     // I need to drill down a level here for searchbar to function...How???
     // ATM search is only filtering the name of the model (ie: DogViewModel) NOT the contents of that model
     // The List cells are already displayed correctly

     NavigationLink(destination:DogView(dog: dog)) {
         HStack{
             // List cell code here works already!
         }
```

Because the list cells are working as they should already with this code I expected the search to be working at the same level. But it's not.

Answer (score 0):

Changing

```
"\($0)".localizedCaseInsensitiveContains(self.searchTerm)
```

to

```
$0.dogName.localizedCaseInsensitiveContains (self.searchTerm)
```

fixed the issue.